# What is main difference between Web Map Service and Tile Map Service

Tags: google-maps, leaflet, gis, wms

I want to understand implementation and performance-based difference. And which is best according to conditions.

Comment: This comment for those who vote down this question, I just want to know which one performance is best over one another....

Answer (score 2):

> What is main difference between Web Map Service and Tile Map Service?

WMS has arbitrary bounds. TMS (as well as WMTS) have predefined bounds.

WMS can give you arbitrary bounding boxes and scale factors, which are calculated in the server at each request. TMS/WMTS can only give a predefined set of bboxes/scales, but the results can be cached quite efficiently.

> And which is best according to conditions?

Depends on your conditions and requisites.

Answer (score 2):

Web Map Service (WMS) supports composing multiple layers server-side, pick arbitrary coordinate reference systems, generate maps in custom bounding boxes expressed in that coordinate system, and specify arbitrary map image sizes and formats.

Web Map Tile Service (WMTS) doesn't support most of those features, and was implemented as a kind of specialized and lean WMS designed for a very specific use (render tiled web maps) with performance in mind.  Thus, unlike WMS, WMTS doesn't do much if any image processing and can pretty much be a proxy to a bunch of ready-made map partitions cached in the server.